# Perl: Scraping a website with frames and javascript

Tags: perl

I have a website with 2 frames. Actions performed in 1 frame(enter data in text box/select radio button/click a href) cause the other frame to load data with javascript. I need to be able to enter data in the first frame and scrape the data in the second. What can I do for this?

Comment: why exactly are you doing this? are you testing the two frames or you simply want to access the information that the second frame provides?

Comment: I want access to the second frame's information

Comment: Are you manually entering data in the first box, or are you doing this with a script?

Comment: I'd like to enter data via the script. Like filling a form from the browser. Similar to how `WWW::Mechanize` does with `submit_form`

Comment: Too little detail. Give a link to the page or provide the mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

Load the website in Firefox, then turn on the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension, enable the 'Net' tab, and have a look at the HTTP data being sent to and from the browser.

Sometimes it can help to try to forget what the webpage looks like, and concentrate on the posts and responses you see in Firebug's Net tab -- that's all you need to reproduce to get your data out.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Reverse engineer the JS (monitoring HTTP traffic can help) to figure out what data actually gets sent to the server and then replicate that in your Perl.
2. Use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) to run a complete browser stack and interrogate it to read the results.

Comment: A reference for reverse engineering JS? That's "All the JS and DOM documentation". There's no shortage of that.

Comment: I am searching Google all around but not able to find the right one.

Comment: There isn't a "right one" but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is good.